# get some attributes from mongodb except one or two

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

I would like to get some information which is in a mongoDB except some attributes.

I tried it in cmd and it worked:

```
db.orders.find({name:"chabeee"},{_id:0, name:1, worksAt:1})
```

Then I get this result:

```
{ "name" : "chabeee", "worksAt" : "jobAtBp" }
{ "name" : "chabeee", "worksAt" : "jobAtRE" }
```

Its okay, but I want to get in a Java Program. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create one additional `BasicDBObject`, which will be used for pointing out which exact keys to be fetched. And finally the [DBCollection#find(DBObject ref, DBObject keys)](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.5/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#find%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject%29) method has to be invoked in order to pass the desired projection keys.

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("name", "chabeee");
BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject();
keys.put("_id", 0);
keys.put("name", 1);
keys.put("worksAt", 1);
BasicDBCursor result = collection.find(query, keys);
```

Then you just have to iterate over the `BasicDBCursor` and verify the result.

```
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next());
}
```